# Copy all files from one place to another whilst keeping group permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I'm trying to copy files from one place to another, I am using this:

```
cp -R /from/ /to/
```

However, whilst this is keeping the standard permissions, it is setting the group permissions to `0 0` (Owner/Group).

How can I copy the files over whilst keeping the correct permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page of `cp`:

```
   -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

   --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,owner‐
          ship,timestamps),  if  possible  additional attributes:
          context, links, xattr, all
```

So, `cp -Rp /from/ to/` should work.